# xarray coordinate concatination

Tags: python, concatenation, coordinates, python-xarray

I have been confused by xr.concat and xr.DataArray for quite some time.
I keep running into an issue with adding new dimensions to an xarray.

I have my data (CP1) with coordinates (lat,lon,time) and would like to add more coordinates (year,month,day,hour) but only the last concat statement becomes a coordinate. My new dimensions do not stay bold as a 'real coordinate'

Is there some kind of argument in the 'dims' and 'coords' that I need to make all my new coordinates 'real coordinates'

In parenthesis it says (time) for my new coordinates instead of the desired.

```
time_pd=time.to_pandas()
time_1=[]
time_2=[]
time_3=[]
time_4=[]
for i in range(len(time)):
    a=datetime.strptime(str(time_pd[i]),'%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00')
    b=a.strftime("%H")
    c=a.strftime("%d")
    d=a.strftime("%Y")
    e=a.strftime("%m")
    time_1.append(b)
    time_2.append(c)
    time_3.append(d)
    time_4.append(e)
time_xr1=xr.DataArray(time_3,dims='year')
time_xr2=xr.DataArray(time_4,dims='month')
time_xr3=xr.DataArray(time_2,dims='day')
time_xr4=xr.DataArray(time_1,dims='hour')


CP4=xr.concat(CP1,time_xr1) #I concat each new coordinate one at a time
CP3=xr.concat(CP4,time_xr2) #Is there a way to do this in a single command
CP2=xr.concat(CP3,time_xr3) #or a way to do it without losing the previous coordinate being bold
CP=xr.concat(CP2,time_xr4)
CP=xr.concat(CP,time)
```

[Image of coordinate results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qfd4n.png)

Comment: Why do you want to add year month day and hour? Do you want to have more control over indexing only values in a certain year for example?

Answer (score 0):

Just a shot in the dark, but if you only want to add those dimension to index with them, e.g. to say you want all values that are in the year 2018, or all values that are at 12PM, then you don't have to do it this way. Instead you can use the xarrays/pandas `.dt` accessor ([documentation](https://docs.xarray.dev/en/latest/user-guide/time-series.html#datetime-component-indexing)).

```
# Everything in year 2018
ds.isel(time=(ds.time.dt.year == 2018))

# Everything at 12 PM
ds.isel(time=(ds.time.dt.hour == 12))
```